# A Rule component to change author on nodes?

Tags: 7, rules, views

I am looking to create a rule's component to allow users to bulk modify the author value on nodes using VBO. Any insight on how I what this component part in rules would look like? The action must allow the user to define whatever author they wish either using a textfield or a list of available accounts on the site in VBO.

Comment: Hi Nigel, this can help you to get the idea: http://vimeo.com/29708898

Comment: THanks, but I have watched those videos many times in the past and also just did a refresher. They are great but unfortunately do not have the answers to my specific need. :(

Comment: Rules works nicely with VBO but for UX crap, I'd suggest implementing your own VBO custom action. You can do this with Rules by fetching entity by ID and setting data value. Not elegant as you need. I do have some examples at my home computer. will try to post an answer tomorrow.

Comment: This really needs to be implemented as a rules component within the UI, with no custom code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a view listing the content that you want to edit.
2. Add a bulk operation in fields

[image]

3. Select change the author of the content

[image]

4. Go to your view to select the nodes for which you want to change the author

[image]

5. Select the author who should be made the new other for all these content.

[image]

Comment: Wow I missed that one completely somehow. THnaks.

Comment: Happens ;) Drupal has so many settings sometimes you can missout the ones staring at you. Has happened many times with me too. Glad it helped.